# How to prevent strcpy from overwriting another variable as well?

Tags: c, string, overwrite, strcpy

I'm trying to make a simple code that converts one type of data into another. I use `strtok` to extract one part of the data and then I run a long serial of `if` conditions to find the right output. However, when the correct output is found and written in the variable `currentNote`, it also seems to overwrite the variable `comma` for a reason I can't figure out. Here is the problematic part of the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char sequence[] = "c1[M],c1[M],d3[L],c3[M],b2[M],(#A-2)[IKN],(#A-1)[L]";
    char copy[] = "";
    char *comma;
    char currentNote[4] = "";

    strcpy(copy, sequence);

    comma = strtok(copy, ",");

    if(strstr(comma, "c1") != 0)     //c1
        {
                printf("%s\n\n", comma);          //Here ...
                strcpy(currentNote, "C5 ");
                printf("%s\n\n", comma);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the outcome :

```
c1[M]

cC5
```

No need to say that `strcpy(currentNote, "C5 ");` is causing it. I don't know why though, I thought it would return `c1[M]` like I would like it to do. After some more experimentation it turns out that the second`printf("%s\n\n", comma);` will always return the first character of `sequence` followed by `C5`. I hope someone can find out, it would be very great.

Comment: Perhaps give `copy` some memory to store stuff in

Comment: That doesn't compile. Where's `currentNote` declared?

Comment: `strcpy(copy, sequence)` is no good. `copy` doesn't have enough space.

Comment: I will try that and see, thanks for the fast answers. Oh it seems like I forgot to add it, I'll edit.

Comment: `char copy[] = "";` means `char copy[1] = "";` .  You should make it big enough, and check there will not be an overflow before calling `strcpy`

Comment: @M.M - My last boyfriend said something similar

Comment: Allright, i indeed tried what everybody suggested and that made the whole thing work! Thank you very much !

Comment: @EdHeal Hopefully he used a wrapper

Comment: "How to prevent strcpy from overwriting another variable as well?" Well, do write anywhere you are not supposed to..

Comment: @d3l: You mena "do**n't**"?

Comment: @Olaf Yep, of course. oops

Comment: BTW `strncpy` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling
`strcpy(copy, sequence)` while `copy` is a 1 element length array.  You need to define it by giving it sufficient size.  Your code as is, is simply a UB. Redefine it like

`char copy[100];`

Or allocate sufficient memory to it dynamically using `malloc`.

Comment: thanks @chux. Always appreciate your feedback. Just edited the answer.